# AngularJS: Defining module dependency at run-time, dynamically

Tags: javascript, angularjs, module

Let's say I have a simple module:

angular.module('Platform', []);

And let's say I have another module:

angular.module('PlatformProductA', []);

Is there an Angular function I can call from JavaScript that will inject module 'PlatformProductA' as a dependency into module 'Platform', *as if* module 'Platform' had been defined like this:

angular.module('Platform', ['PlatformProductA']);

In other words, **after** a module has been defined, I need to inject another module into it as a dependency.

EDIT:

I'm not sure how, but this seems to work:

```
angular.module('Platform', []);
angular.module('PlatformProductA', []);
angular.module('Platform').requires.push('PlatformProductA');
```

Angular somehow sees that 'PlatformProductA' has been injected?

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is $injector, which allows dynamic injection

```
angular.module('Platform', [$injector], function(){ // don't remember exact syntax
    $scope.myModule = $injector.get('PlatformProductA');
});
```

Comment: That's not what he's asking for. injector only applies to services and other injectables within a module he's literally talking about including one module in another after the fact where you've identified each module ahead of time as not having any injectables.